# Not able to boot my ubuntu due to ACPI error

Tags: acpi, initramfs

Don't know why my ubuntu is not booting up. It is showing

BusyBox v1.30.1 (ubuntu 1:1.30.1-6ubuntu3.1) built-in shell

And after some time it is showing

ACPI:Error: cannot release Mutux[PATM]

When I tried to run fsck /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root then fsck.ext4 error it is showing.

Comment: Your question reads like there is another error after the fsck command?

Comment: @David now in busybox it is showing ACPI error cannot release mutux.